# Removing item from data provider of uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

IOS newb trying to remove an item from a table view using reusable cells. how do I know which item I need to remove and how do I remove it. The data comes from a network call, the cells have their own xib/class. I put a property on the cell class to be able to get their data. here is my current code. it crashes when it tries to remove the item from the data provider.

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete){
    //find object to be deleted
    MessagesCell *curCell = (MessagesCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    for (int i=0;i<[messagesArray count]; i++) {
        if ([[CommonAPI checkForNullNumber:curCell.allData[@"id"]] integerValue] ==[[CommonAPI checkForNullNumber:((NSDictionary *)[messagesArray objectAtIndex:i])[@"id"]] integerValue]) {
            [messagesArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        }
    }
}
[messagesTable reloadData];
}
```

it gets into the remove call so I doubt it's my loop even though there has to be a better way of finding the data for the cell from the dataprovider. anyway thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of error are you seeing when the application crashes?

Answer (score 0):

First you have get object remove  and update

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
       MyClass * object = [messagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [messagesArray removeObject:object];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Newby problem. I instantiated the nsMutableArray from the array dictionary in the response from the network call. So I was instantiating the nsmutable array as a NSArray. which dies when you try to change any element in it. So to fix the issue I instantiated the array correctly.

So the incorrect way is

```
 messagesArray = response[@"data"];
```

the correct way

```
 messagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:response[@"data"]];
```

Thanks for the help.